# dojo app - caching static content such as imgs/css

Tags: dojo, cache-control, dojo-build

Im working on and existing dojo application which is requesting the same static content on every page change.

Is there a way to configure the application so this content is cached?.... i.e so every http request has cache control headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing related with Dojo or any other javascript framework.

You can define the cache control configurations either in the Content Server (Apache / Nginx)  or in the application server. (if the content is created by the backend server).